# Parse.User.logIn gets stuck

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I have made a user login function:

```
export const userLogin = (email, password) => (dispatch) => {
    console.log(email, password);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_STARTED });
  console.log("after dispatch");
  Parse.User.logIn(email, password, {
    success(user) {
        console.log("in success");
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        user: user.toJSON(),
      });
     window.location.replace('/');
    },
    error(user, error) {
        console.log("in error")
      console.log({ error });
      // The login failed. Check error to see why.
      dispatch({
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR,
        error,
      });
    },
  });
};
```

but it always gets stuck after `Parse.User.logIn` it doesn't go in a success or in error. I have logged the email and password and they are correct.

So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Parse.User.Login` [does not have any third parameter](https://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/2.1.0/Parse.FacebookUtils.html#.logIn). You should be using the [promise functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then):

```
Parse.User.logIn(email, password)
  .then((user) => {
    console.log("in success");
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      user: user.toJSON(),
    });
    window.location.replace('/');
  })
  .error((user, error) => {
    console.log("in error")
    console.log({ error });
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR,
      error,
    });
  });
```

Or, if you're fancy enough, you can use the new `await` syntax (Which I think is a bit cleaner):

```
export const userLogin = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  console.log(email, password);
  dispatch({ type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_STARTED });
  console.log("after dispatch");

  try {
    const user = await Parse.User.logIn(email, password);
    console.log("in success");
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      user: user.toJSON(),
    });
    window.location.replace('/');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("in error")
    console.log({ error });
    // The login failed. Check error to see why.
    dispatch({
      type: actionTypes.AUTH_LOGIN_ERROR,
      error,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Also: Double check the parameters on error. I doubt it returns any user object (Just `error`)

Comment: Curious, did you use the first or second option @FaizanAhmad?

Comment: I used second option